# veutify v-menu how to set a responsive and fixed width of the border menu

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with Vue.js and Vuetify and I am making a large word appear from a dropdown menu, using `v-menu` but the menu currently will format the menu options to be as big as the text you put in the dropdown part, instead i want the text to be responsive to how the big v-menu dropdown part is

Comment: Have you checked the API to see if any of the props will help you? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?